# install monodevelop-database (4.0.12+dfsg-1) from GIT repository

Tags: 14.04, git, mono, monodevelop

I cloned the Git repository `git://anonscm.debian.org/pkg-cli-apps/packages/monodevelop-database.git` and tried to run  `./configure` but it gives me this error:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for mono... /usr/bin/mono
checking for dmcs... /usr/bin/dmcs
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for UNMANAGED_DEPENDENCIES_MONO... yes
checking for mono... /usr/bin/mono
checking for dmcs... /usr/bin/dmcs
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for MONO_ADDINS... no
configure: error: Package requirements (mono-addins >= 0.4) were not met:

No package 'mono-addins' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables MONO_ADDINS_CFLAGS
and MONO_ADDINS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I am running MonoDevelop Version 4.0.12 and Mono 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1).
What error is this and what do i do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have the `mono-addins` package from this line: `No package 'mono-addins' found`

Install it using this command in the terminal and then try again:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-addins
```